# Three JS Material to see behind current div

Tags: three.js

Is there any material that would allow an object in a scene with this material to, wherever it is visibly rendered, show whatever is in the dom element behind the renderer's dom element?

In other words what do I need to do to the object "?" below such that viewer would see "D" instead of "C" whenever "B" is not blocking "?"?

```
Rendered     |            Scene          | Lower DOM Element
             |                           |
             |                           |      D                                               
    B        |      B              C     |      D                                               
    B        |      B       ?      C     |      D                                               
    B        |      B       ?      C     |      D                                               
    B        |      B       ?      C     |      D                                               
    B        |      B       ?      C     |      D                                               
    B        |      B       ?      C     |      D                                                   
    B        |      B       ?      C     |      D                                               
    D        |              ?      C     |      D                                               
    D        |              ?      C     |      D                                               
    D        |              ?      C     |      D                                               
    D        |              ?      C     |      D                                               
    C        |                     C     |      D         
    C        |                     C     |      D
```

- In the above, the scene and lower dom element are supposed to be absolutely positioned so that they overlap with the scene on top.
- The scene is shown as a birds eye view with the user looking from the left.

Comment: Interestingly, there is a 3d module design just for this https://brentongunning.github.io/voodoo.js/

Comment: It apparently supports three as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See-through Background**

There is. You're looking for the `WebGLRenderer` alpha option and `setClearAlpha` function:

```
// Enables the canvas to be transparent
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });

// Makes the backaground completely transparent
renderer.setClearAlpha(0);
```

You can see this in an example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oQrPzO.

**See-through Object**

It sounds like you're interested in making rendered object behave as a "window" into the dom behind the canvas. That can be achieved with the `opacity` material setting:

```
// Set up a renderer with a white background
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
renderer.setClearAlpha(0);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);

// ...
// Create a material to behave as a window
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ opacity: 0.5, transparent: false });
```

It is important that the `transparent` option be set to `false` so that no blending occurs and the alpha is written directly to the canvas. Here's another example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oQrPzO.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect! That does it!

Comment: So this approach doesn't seem to work when I add lights to the scene. Same problem with Directional and Ambient light. When they are present the previously clear "window" becomes colored with the light. Any idea how to work around that?

Comment: It depends on what your desired effect is. If you just want a solid field you can probably use the `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial`, which isn't affected by lights.